# SQL server data copy bug?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have one query who shows some data, and those data I'm manually copying to Table1.

The query shows the numeric type and it is in this form

```
          Query
    +---------------+
    |    status     |
    +---------------+
    | 1370.00000000 |
    | 2850.00000000 |
    | 426.00000000  |
    | 289.00000000  |
    | 2000.00000000 |
    +---------------+
```

And when i select it and right click,copy and copy it to other table who is numeric(28,2) it shows the data this way. I have tried changing it to numeric(28,2) but it's almost the same, also decimal type.

```
        Table1
+-----------------------+
|        status1        |
+-----------------------+
| 137000000000.00000000 |
| 285000000000.00000000 |
| 42600000000.00000000  |
| 28900000000.00000000  |
| 200000000000.00000000 |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: I'm running sql server 2005

Comment: Why are you using copy/paste?  Why not just `SELECT INTO`?

Comment: I'm running a query, where I need to change date from and date to, and I copy the result to another table...

Comment: What does "manually copying" mean? From where, *exactly*? To where, *exactly*?

Comment: It means that i go with the mouse to the result windows and right click,chose select all and again right click copy.

Comment: @FiN - don't do "cut and paste" like that.  As @Kris mentioned above, look at `SELECT ... INTO` in Books Online.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750%28v=sql.105%29.aspx for details

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using "Copy-and-paste" to copy from the user-interface; use a T-SQL script to copy the rows from one table to another.

Setup a test-bed with two tables, one will be the source, the other the destination:

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE dbo.StatusTable1
(
    StatusNumber NUMERIC(18,10)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.StatusTable2
(
    StatusNumber NUMERIC(28,2)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.StatusTable1 (StatusNumber)
VALUES (1370.00000000)
    , (2850.00000000)
    , (426.00000000)
    , (289.00000000)
    , (2000.00000000);
```

this part copies rows from StatusTable1 to StatusTable2:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.StatusTable2 (StatusNumber)
SELECT st.StatusNumber
FROM dbo.StatusTable1 st;
```

Show the content of both tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.StatusTable1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.StatusTable2;
```

Cleanup the test-bed:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.StatusTable1;
DROP TABLE dbo.StatusTable2;
```

The results:

[image]